# Write an query to sort customers from most important to least one

Tags: sql

I am very new to SQL. I have three tables such as transactions, products, and customers. I like to write a query to sort from the most important customer to the least one.
But, it shows me each customer multiple times. I would to have distinct customers from the most important to less important in terms of the quantity they purchased.

```
Select c.id , c.first_name , c.last_name, t.quantity
From transactions as t , customer_data as c
INNER JOIN transactions ON t.customer_id = c.id
ORDER by t.quantity DESC
```

Comment: You are getting a cross join on `transactions` as you reference it twice with only one join condition. You also need a `group by` and `sum`

Comment: It is solved. Many thanks

Comment: @Alirezaaaa74 Please add an answer that shows the query which solved it.

Comment: I wrote the answer dear Jonas

Answer (score 0):

Select     c.first_name , c.last_name, t.quantity

From      transactions as t , customer_data as c

INNER JOIN     transactions ON t.customer_id = c.id

GROUP by   c.first_name
ORDER by    t.quantity DESC

Comment: Your answer is wrong. You still have the issue that `transactions as t , customer_data as c INNER JOIN transactions ON t.customer_id = c.id` gives you a cross join on `transactions` and you are not using `group by` with any aggregation such as `sum` - the way you are using `group by` would be invalid in most RDBMS and likely give you non deterministic results in the rest

Comment: probably you need `Select c.id , c.first_name , c.last_name, t.quantity From (SELECT customer_id, SUM(quantity) AS quantity FROM transactions GROUP BY customer_id ) AS t INNER JOIN customer_data as c ON t.customer_id = c.id ORDER by t.quantity DESC`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).